# Grab last 12 bytes of a bytes32

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, assembly, bytecode

How do I grab the last 12 bytes of a `bytes32` in assembly?

For example, the last 12 bytes of `bytes32 num = 0xdeb02111e4e5fa8c7c05e983a3446893a36d12ad6d79206163636f756e740000`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it on solidity using explicit type cast or convert to bytes and use index slicing, but if you want to do it in assembly the best way is to shift left 160 bit using `shl(160,num)`. This leaves you 96 bits (12 bytes) on the most significant bytes. You can cast them to your `bytes12` type afterward:

```
contract Test{
    function test() public view returns(bytes12){
        bytes32 num = 0xdeb02111e4e5fa8c7c05e983a3446893a36d12ad6d79206163636f756e740000;
        bytes12 res1 = bytes12(uint96(uint256(num)));
        bytes12 res2 = bytes12(num<<160);
        
        bytes12 res3;
        assembly {
            res3 := shl(160,num)
        }
        require(res1 == res2);
        require(res2 == res3);
        return res3;
    }
}
```

Output :
`0:bytes12: 0x6d79206163636f756e740000`